# How to show entries depending on the authority

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have 4 entities in my jHipster project : user, department, userAssignmentToDepartments(user may belongs to several departments), order. Order entitey has fiel "department_id". The quiestions are:

1. How to show only orders with department_id  included in 
   userAssignmentToDepartments for this user?

2.How to get  departments id's  which user has authority?

order.routes.ts

```
export const orderRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'order',
        component: OrderComponent,
        resolve: {
            pagingParams: JhiResolvePagingParams
        },
       data: {
           authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
           defaultSort: 'id,asc',
           pageTitle: 'Orders'
       },
       canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
    }...
```

order.service.ts

```
export class OrderService {
query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http
        .get<IOrder[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' })
        .pipe(map((res: EntityArrayResponseType) => this.convertDateArrayFromServer(res)));
}.....
```

order.component.ts

```
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

loadAll() {
    this.orderService
        .query({
            page: this.page - 1,
            size: this.itemsPerPage,
            sort: this.sort()
        })
        .subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IOrder[]>) => this.paginateOrders(res.body, res.headers),
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
}
```

department.model.ts

```
export interface IDepartment {
   id?: number;
   name?: string;
```

}

```
export class Departmetn implements IDepartment {
   constructor(public id?: number, public name?: string) {}
```

}

order.model.ts

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';

export interface IOrder {
   id?: number;
   date?: Moment;
   departmetnId?: number

}

export class Order implements IOrder {
    constructor(public id?: number, public date?: Moment, public departmentId?: number) {}
```

}

user.model.ts

```
export interface IUser {
   id?: number;
}

export class User implements IUser {
    constructor(public id?: number) {}
}
```

user-assignment.ts

```
export interface IUserAssignment {
   id?: number;
   userLogin?: string;
   userId?: number;
   centerName?: string;
   centerId?: number;
}

export class UserAssignment implements IUserAssignment {
constructor(
       public id?: number,
       public userLogin?: string,
       public userId?: number,
       public departmentName?: string,
       public departmentId?: number
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: Please provide the structures of your entities.

Comment: I edited post for that.

Comment: Why doing it client-side? It'd be more efficient to do it server-side.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Gael.I will think this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume these are your assignments and orders lists

```
userAssignments : IUserAssignment[]
orders : IOrder[]
```

For getting orders with department_id included in userAssignmentToDepartments for a user

```
getOrders(userID : number){
    var deptList : number[] = []
    for(let assignment of this.userAssignments){
        if(assignment.userId==userID){
            deptList.push(assignment.departmentId);
        }
    }
    var orderList : IOrder[]
    for(let order of this.orders){
        if(deptList.find(dept => dept==order.departmentId)){
            orderList.push(order);
        }
    }
    console.log(orderList);
}
```

For getting departments authorized for specific user,

```
getAuthorizedDepts(userID : number){
    var deptList : number[] = []
    for(let assignment of this.userAssignments){
        if(assignment.userId==userID){
            deptList.push(assignment.departmentId);
        }
    }
    console.log(deptList)
}
```